# C++ templates and Unsigned long problems

Tags: c++, templates

I am intending to make a constant Vector

```
const  madness::Vector<double,3> kvec(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

By calling the following code

```
template <typename T>
Vector<T,3> vec(T x, T y, T z) {
   Vector<T,3> r; r[0] = x; r[1] = y; r[2] = z;
   return r;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error which seems to say

```
extra.cc:216: error: no matching function for call to ‘madness::Vector<double, 3ul>::Vector(double, double, double)’
note: candidates are: madness::Vector<T, N>::Vector(const madness::Vector<T, N>&) [with T = double, long unsigned int N = 3ul]
note:                 madness::Vector<T, N>::Vector() [with T = double, long unsigned int N = 3ul]
```

I can't help but notice the 3ul in the error message. Why does the compiler think my innocent little three is an unsigned long?

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Comment: probably because you've told it to. show your code. folks here are not telepaths

Comment: is there a difference between kvec and vec or is that a typo...

Comment: I can't help but notice the call to a 3-arg constructor in the error message. - you aren't calling `vec`, you're declaring an object called `kvec`. What is the declared type of the second template parameter of `Vector`? I'm guessing it's `unsigned long`. But as Alf says, you're the only one here who can check your code to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your Vector class template perhaps:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> class Vector ...
```

And is your size_t perhaps an unsigned long?

Also, I suspect you really meant:

```
const  madness::Vector<double,3> kvec = vec(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Indeed, vec() not a constructor. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your `vec` function then you need to do

```
const  madness::Vector<double,3> kvec( vec(0.0, 0.0, 1.0) );
```

which will use the copy constructor ultimately. The way you've written it you would need to give the vector class a constructor that takes three doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor that takes 3 double. You haven't got one yet, or you declared it wrongly or instead of a constructor you want to use aggregate initialization using `= { ... }`. Choose what fits.

As for the `3u` - you most probably declared the corresponding template parameter as `unsigned long int`.

Notice that this has an important consequence

```
template<typename T, int N>
void f(Vector<T, N> v);

// will not work, since "N" is an int, not an "unsigned long int"!
f(kvec);
```

You need to know the exact type of the non-type template parameter to be able to deduce arguments. In this case, you would need `N` to be a `unsigned long int`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor that takes three three inputs. Like so:

```
template <unsigned int T, class N>
class Vector {
public:
  // ...
  Vector(T x, T y, T z);
  // ..
};
```